# How to disable the context menu of a QDockWidget title bar

Tags: qt, contextmenu, qdockwidget

I have a couple of QDockWidgets that are all not closabale (using Qt 5.6). Therefore, the context menu that is displayed when right-clicking a title bar of one of them only has disabled entries, and I would like to disable the whole context menu.

I tried to set the contextMenuPolicy to NoContextMenu without success.

I then tried to use a subclass of QDockWidget, override the ContextMenuEvent and ignore it. The menu is still displayed.

I then tried to install an event filter to catch the ContextMenuEvent, but it did not catch any, just PaintEvents, ResizeEvents etc.

I'm out of ideas … any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried just setting the [context menu policy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop)?

Comment: Yes, I also tried this without success … I just forgot to write it up there ;-)

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far.  Setting the dock widget's context menu policy to [`Qt::PreventContextMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ContextMenuPolicy-enum) works for me.

Comment: That's it! I set it to Qt::NoContextMenu, and that didn't work, so I thought this wasn't possible this way. Thanks for the hint! Do you want to post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the comments it is necessary to set the context menu policy on the `QDockWidget` to `Qt::PreventContextMenu`...

```
dock_widget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);
```

rather than simply `Qt::NoContextMenu`.  From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ContextMenuPolicy-enum) `Qt::NoContextMenu` simply defers the context menu handling to the parent widget rather than preventing it entirely.