# Qt: right mouse click handling on QDockWidget title

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qdockwidget

Clicking right mouse button on any QDockWidget title causes list of all QDockWidget in application.
To disable this beheavor I implemented special title class

```cpp
class QMyTitleBar : public QLabel
{
public:
    QMyTitleBar(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags()) : QLabel(parent, f)
    {
    }

    QMyTitleBar(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags()) : QLabel(text, parent, f)
    {
    }

    ~QMyTitleBar()
    {
    }

protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * qevent) override
{
    if (qevent->button() == Qt::MouseButton::RightButton)
    {
        qevent->accept();
        return;
    }
}

void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * qevent) override
{
    if (qevent->button() == Qt::MouseButton::RightButton)
    {
        qevent->accept();
        return;
    }
}
```

and set to my QDockWidget this custom title widget

```
myDockWidget->setTitleBarWidget(new QMyTitleBar(QObject::tr("My Title")));
```

but this does not work. It handles mouse event but menu with all QDockWidgets appears.
How can I remove this menu?

Comment: try: (parent, Qt::Window | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint |
        Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dock_widget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);`

From: [How to disable the context menu of a QDockWidget title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601362/how-to-disable-the-context-menu-of-a-qdockwidget-title-bar)

Comment: Thanks! I hed a trouble to find the anser